why pyautogui isn't working when i try to click the x,y?
I'm trying to use PyAutoGUI to click inside a web browser window. I have this code:
import gi, pyautogui

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class App(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        #Configurando a janela
        super().__init__(title='004')
        self.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_resizable(False)
        self.set_border_width(1)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        #Botões
        self.btFechar = Gtk.Button(label='Iniciar')

        def Bt1(self):
            pyautogui.click(1711,150)
            pyautogui.typewrite("Hello, world!", interval=0.25)

        self.btFechar.connect("clicked", Bt1)
        self.add(self.btFechar)

        # Finalizando
        self.show_all() # Esta Linha Mostra Tudo Da Janela

app = App()
Gtk.main()

When I click on the button in the program, it should click in a text field on the web page and type some text. But it doesn't seem to do anything - the mouse stays in that window.
Why does this happen, and how can I make it work properly?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. To click in a different window, you need to focus that window first. That isn't a "how does PyAutoGUI work?" thing, but a "how does the window manager work?" thing - and it's the same across basically every window manager for every system. It will be the same for you with GNOME on Debian as it is for others with Explorer on Windows - this is just how GUIs have worked, since the 70s. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

For future questions, please read [ask] and How to debug small programs, and try to diagnose more carefully before posting. For example, in this case you could try making a program that only creates the GTK window and then tries the click automatically (without waiting for you to use the button). Or a program that just tries to click immediately, without doing any GTK stuff.

Please also try to be more clear about problems. With the original question, at first I was confused, because I thought you wanted to click somewhere else in the GTK window. Of course you wouldn't be able to type text at that location in the GTK app that you show, because you didn't create a text field there.

did you try with other pages or with other programs? Maybe problem is only with browser or only with one web page.

your code works for me when I use it with web page Stackoverflow.com in Firefox on Linux. I changed coordinates to click field Search ... (at the top of page) and it puts text in this field.
